# Recursive Logic to Handle Document Count Based on Page Number Passed in Request

Tags: javascript, recursion

In my Node/MongoDB backend I am returning a count to my Angular front-end, which is then used by the logic in our front-end to serve up pagination UI for the end user.

Because one section of our data is quite large (so the count takes quite a while to come back), I am instead passing counts incrementally, based on the page passed in with the request. This makes everything load much faster. It's only once the user gets to page 70 (which is not common in our use case with this internal app) that I trigger a call for the entire count to be returned:

```
if (this.parameters.category === 'all') {
  this.documentCount = 120;
  let pageNumber = parseInt(this.parameters.page);
  if (pageNumber >= 9 && pageNumber < 19) this.documentCount = 240;
  if (pageNumber >= 19 && pageNumber < 29) this.documentCount = 360;
  if (pageNumber >= 29 && pageNumber < 39) this.documentCount = 480;
  if (pageNumber >= 39 && pageNumber < 49) this.documentCount = 600;
  if (pageNumber >= 49 && pageNumber < 59) this.documentCount = 720;
  if (pageNumber >= 59 && pageNumber < 69) this.documentCount = 840;
  if (pageNumber >= 69) {
    this.documentCount = await this.getDocumentCount(mongooseModelObject, (searchObject = {}), override);
  }
  return this.documentCount;
}
```

Now, while this works, it's not very succinct. I'm wondering, rather than hard-coding math values like this, if I can use some recursive code to basically replicate this logic. That way I wouldn't have to hard-code a block of logic for each `pageNumber` case, and I could actually just keep passing another 120 records each time, until the total count is hit. Is this do-able? What would this look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 return 120 * (Math.floor((pageNumber + 1) / 10) + 1);
```

And I would be careful with this "bigger than 70 show them all" thing (thats why I omitted it) cause it might get you in trouble if the collection is really large. You should always limit the number of returned results.

Comment: Happy to delete my answer, not sure who got there first, wasn't goal-hanging!

Comment: @marcus you can't be "first", just "right" or "wrong". There are so many answers on SO, just leave it there

Comment: Very true, but I try and be respectful of other users and didn't want to give the impression I wasn't!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need recursion to solve this problem. You just need to abstract the mathematical relationship between the page number and the shorthand document count.

```
if (this.parameters.category === 'all') {
  let pageNumber = parseInt(this.parameters.page);
  if (pageNumber < 69) {
      return getShorthandPageNumber(pageNumber);

  }
  return await this.getDocumentCount(mongooseModelObject, (searchObject = {}), override);
 }

// Then the declaration of getShorthandPageNumber is:

function getShorthandPageNumber(pageNumber) {
    return (Math.floor((pageNumber + 1) / 10) + 1) * 120;
}
```

Notice I've removed the assignment to this.documentCount from the first function in order to make it a pure function, but that is not necessary.

Comment: I appreciate how you added detail here with the abstracted function. Makes sense to use that. I am marking the other answer as correct because it showed up first, but many thanks for this, @Marcus.